# .append a new div with pictures in it

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, append

I am coding a Flask app with the use of AJAX. The user makes a query and each time the answer appears in a new div; for instance he asks for a place and the app displays two pictures of that place plus a wikipedia article.
 Problem is each time the user makes a query, the two pictures are displayed as well in the previous div, only the last div as only the two pictures in it.

```
    $("#chatbox").append( "<p class = display_question>"+data['user_question']+"</p>" );                            
    $("#user_form")[0].reset();
    $("#chatbox").append("<div class = pictures> </div>");       
    $(".pictures").append($('<img id = wiki_img>').attr('src', data['wiki_pic']));
    $(".pictures").append($('<img id = img>').attr('src', data['response']));        
    $("#chatbox").append( "<p class = wikidata>"+data['wiki_data']+"</p>" );
```

Is there a way to append the div with the two pictures in it without adding them to the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the right element (only the last `div.pictures`) ; before you was selecting all the `div.pictures` ; see [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$("#chatbox").append( "<p class = display_question>"+data['user_question']+"</p>" );                            
$("#user_form")[0].reset();
$("#chatbox").append("<div class = pictures> </div>");       

// Append pictures to last element of class .pictures only
$(".pictures").last().append($('<img id = wiki_img>').attr('src', data['wiki_pic']));
$(".pictures").last().append($('<img id = img>').attr('src', data['response']));        

$("#chatbox").append( "<p class = wikidata>"+data['wiki_data']+"</p>" );
```